# Define list for multiple use

Tags: xparse, comma-separated-list, listofitems

I want to repurpose a predefined comma separated list multiple times in the document. As a minimal example, have a look at the following code which does not work as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand*{\listtotestA}{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

\def\listtotestB{
    D,
    E,
    F
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \teslist{m}{
    \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{
        Output: ##1 \\
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\teslist{\listtotestA}
\\
\teslist{\listtotestB}

\end{document}
```

Instead of

```
Output: A
Output: B
Output: C

Output: D
Output: E
Output: F
```

It produces

```
Output: A,B,C

Output: D,E,F
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to expand the list macro first: `\clist_map_inline:on {#1}{...}` or `\clist_map_inline:Vn {#1}{...}`

Comment: (You probably need to define the corresponding variant first...) It would be cleaner not to mix l2e code with l3 code but a good recommendation would require to know a bit more about the use case you have in mind…

Comment: Actually the lists consist of filenames I want to include, i.e. system paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `listofitems` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems}

\newcommand*{\listtotestA}{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

\def\listtotestB{
    D,
    E,
    F
}

\newcommand\teslist[1]{%
    \readlist*\mylist{#1}%
    \foreachitem\x\in\mylist{Output: \x\\}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\teslist{\listtotestA}

\noindent\teslist{\listtotestB}

\end{document}
```

[image]